# prototype extending jquery not working in internet explorer - "Not supported"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, prototype

I extended jQuery with some prototypes to validate forms.

```
if($('#mydiv').valid()) { /*do submit stuff*/}
```

It works perfectly in Firefox but IE11 gives me:
"Object does not support the property or method"
in Italian "L'oggetto non supporta la proprietà o il metodo 'valid'"

Thanks and happy new year

Comment: what object is not does not support what property? You can console.log some things in your code and press F12 to open the developer tools for IE. For example `console.log($().valid)` or `console.log(typeof $().valid)`

Comment: How exactly are you adding this `valid` method to jQuery?

Comment: You need to show the code on how you extended it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
IE debug was reporting the error but the problem was due to a function that had a php-like argument initialization:

```
function aaa(a="some thing"){
//stuff
}
```

I replaced with:

```
function aaa(a){
if(!a) a="some thing";
//stuff
}
```

Thank you